# add dependet values and and return all matched

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I would like to add another dependency to look for in arrays. So if a user types the name of a student and the subject list,all the results of the supportlist are showed.

I have setup 3 arrays  but i'm not sure how to go further.

```
gs code

function getStudentInfo(studentName){ 
//var lookupValue = "support";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws =ss.getSheetByName("logboek1");
var lc =ss.getLastColumn();
//var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues()[0];
var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), lc).getValues();
//var index = data.indexOf(lookupValue) + 1;

var studentNameList = data.map(function(r) { return r[0]; }); 
var subjectList = data.map(function(r) { return r[1]; });      
var supportList = data.map(function(r) { return r[4]; }); 

//Logger.log(supportList); 

var position = studentNameList.indexOf(studentName);   
if(position > -1){
return subjectList[position]; 

js  code
 }  
function getEstimate(){

var zipCode = document.getElementById("zip").value;

if(zipCode){
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateEstimate).getCost(zipCode);         

   } 

} 
function updateEstimate(cost){
document.getElementById("est").value =cost; 
M.updateTextFields();

}    
function getEstimate1(){

var studentName = document.getElementById("zip1").value;
if(studentName){

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatestudentInfo)
.getStudentInfo(studentName);         

   } 
    } 
function updatestudentInfo(info){
document.getElementById("est1").value =info; 
M.updateTextFields();
```

Wat i would like is to add another dependency. So if a user types the studentName, (if the subjects are available for that student)chooses for the subjectList(that are available for that student) and then gets all of the results of the supportlist that belongs by the student.